# How to checkout reactos sources including all tags and branches as SVN working copy or git clone?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, react-os

My research results so far are:

- checking out http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/, http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/ and http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos cause relocation error (

  ```
  $ LANG=C svn co http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/ reactos-svn
  Redirecting to URL 'http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos':
  Redirecting to URL 'http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos':
  svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos'
  ```
- git clones I found so far (unpreferrable solution because it's not nice to depend on the mirror availability and activity for updates):

  - https://github.com/mirror/reactos: mirrors trunk only
  - https://github.com/svn2github/reactos mirrors trunk/reactos only
- `subgit configure --svn-url <tried all URLs listed above> reactos` fails because `svn checkout` subcommand fails
- creating a clone with http://svn2github.com/ fails with error message `Cannot connect to SVN repository at http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/`

EDIT 1: There seems to be a read-only git mirror provided by ReactOS team browsable at http://git.reactos.org/?p=reactos.git;a=summary, but no checkout URL for git (and I can't figure it out myself).

Comment: According to [site](http://reactos.org/development/source-control), you have to use svn:// protocol, not http://

Comment: OK, got it! I went over https://reactos.org/de/reactos-herunterladen and then found http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/ from the sourceforge link...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't checkout *now* in single step, but you can

- Inform about obvious misconfiguration repository-maintaner
- Checkout in the `svn co`: /trunk, /tags and /branches can be checkouted without redirect-loop

I **can** checkout trunk without loop

```
>svn co ...
...
 U   reactos
Checked out revision 63899.
>svn --version
svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
   compiled Aug 10 2014, 14:54:56 on x86-microsoft-windows
```

Comment: checking out `/trunk` doesn't work due to redirection error neither (is available as git transformation on github.com though - no idea why it works for them). I'll consider the first option... Thanks!

Comment: Must be a bug in svn 1.8.8, with 1.8.10 (r1615264) checkout works as expected over svn protocol...

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else finds this when looking for a git checkout url

`git clone git://git.reactos.org/reactos.git`

Answer (score 1):

ReactOS now hosts their code directly on github. You can check it out using https `git clone https://github.com/reactos/reactos/`, or (if you have your ssh public key in github) via ssh `git clone git@github.com:reactos/reactos`.

If you prefer, you can also work with the code via gitpod (https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/reactos/reactos).